# conditional context.drawImage() function

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, conditional-statements, drawimage

I have a context.drawImage() function inside a draw function of a class.

When I pass static values it works just fine:
context.drawImage(this.image, this.position.x -12, this.position.y -12)

But what I want is a conditional passing of values:
context.drawImage( this.scared ? this.image, this.position.x -12, this.position.y -12 : this.imageScared, this.position.x -12, this.position.y -12 ).

And this is not working.

```js
class Ghost {
  static speed = 2;
  constructor({position, velocity, color = 'red', image, imageScared}) {
    this.position = position;
    this.velocity = velocity;
    this.radius = 15 * 0.8;
    this.color = color;
    this.prevCollisions = []
    this.speed = 2;
    this.scared = false;
    this.image = image;
    this.imageScared = imageScared;
  }
  draw() {
    context.beginPath();
context.arc(this.position.x,this.position.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2)
context.fillStyle = this.scared ? 'blue' : this.color;
context.fill();
context.closePath();
context.drawImage( if (this.scared) { this.image, this.position.x -12, this.position.y -12 } else { this.imageScared, this.position.x -12, this.position.y -12 } )
  }
  update() {
    this.draw();
    this.position.x += this.velocity.x;
    this.position.y += this.velocity.y;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you used the ternary operator and then wrote an `if` statement as an argument?
Anyways, you can use ternary in your `context.drawImage` statement.

`context.drawImage( this.scared ? this.image : this.imageScared, this.position.x -12, this.position.y -12 );`

```js
    class Ghost {
      static speed = 2;
      constructor({position, velocity, color = 'red', image, imageScared}) {
        this.position = position;
        this.velocity = velocity;
        this.radius = 15 * 0.8;
        this.color = color;
        this.prevCollisions = []
        this.speed = 2;
        this.scared = false;
        this.image = image;
        this.imageScared = imageScared;
      }
      draw() {
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(this.position.x,this.position.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2)
        context.fillStyle = this.scared ? 'blue' : this.color;
        context.fill();
        context.closePath();
        context.drawImage( this.scared ? this.image : this.imageScared, this.position.x -12, this.position.y -12 );
      }
      update() {
        this.draw();
        this.position.x += this.velocity.x;
        this.position.y += this.velocity.y;
      }
    }
```

Comment: works pretty great.

Answer (score 1):

First web developer rule: Work with the developer tools open. Just press F12 and check your console for errors, and you'll find what is happening. Even if you press the "Run code snippet" the error shows. You have bad syntax.

Maybe in other language that makes sense, but not in JavaScript. You cannot have conditional arguments depending on an if, inlining the if inside the arguments.

Just change this line

```js
context.drawImage( if (this.scared) { this.image, this.position.x -12, this.position.y -12 } else { this.imageScared, this.position.x -12, this.position.y -12 } )
```

to this line

```js
if (this.scared) {
    context.drawImage(this.image, this.position.x - 12, this.position.y - 12)
} else {
    context.drawImage(this.imageScared, this.position.x - 12, this.position.y - 12)
)
```

You can also use a ternary on each argument, but I think that this code is closer to your code, so you'll understand the difference.